# Matrix exponent eigenvalues

Tags: eigenvalues-eigenvectors, lie-groups, matrix-exponential

I was thinking about this for quite some time and didn't find it nowhere. So I hope someone can help me.

let $e:\frak{gl}$$(n,R)$ $\to Gl(n,R)$ be the exponential application.

I know that if $v$ is a eigenvetor of $A$ with eigenvalue $\lambda$, then 
$$e^Av=e^{\lambda}v.$$

My question is:

if $e^Av=v$ for a nonzero $v$ (i.e. 1 is a eigenvalue of $e^A$), can I conclude that $A$ necessarily has $0$ as one of its eigenvalue?

---

I'm specially interested in the case that A is $$
\begin{pmatrix} 
0 & -1 \\
1 & 0 
\end{pmatrix}$$
I want to prove that if $e^Av=v$ then $v=0$ (because A doesn't have $0$ as it eigenvalue).

Comment: Could $A$ have $i 2\pi$ as an eigenvalue?

Comment: A could have $i$ or $-i$ as eigenvalue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> if $e^Av=v$ for a nonzero $v$ (i.e. 1 is a eigenvalue of $e^A$), can I conclude that $A$ necessarily has $0$ as one of its eigenvalue?

No. For instance,

$$\begin{pmatrix} 
0 & - 2 \pi \\
2 \pi & 0
\end{pmatrix}$$

does not have 0 as an eigenvalue, yet its matrix exponential is the identity matrix, which does have 1 as an eigenvalue.

> I'm specially interested in the case that A is $$
> \begin{pmatrix} 
> 0 & -1 \\
> 1 & 0 
> \end{pmatrix}$$

The exponential of this matrix is 
$$
\begin{pmatrix} 
\cos(1) & -\sin(1) \\
\sin(1) & \cos(1)
\end{pmatrix}$$

which has only complex eigenvalues and so does not have any fixed vectors.

> I want to prove that if $e^Av=v$ then $v=0$ (because A doesn't have $0$ as it eigenvalue).

For this particular $e^A$, the statement is true, but not for the reason you claim, but rather from an explicit computation of the nullspace of $e^A$.

Comment: Thanks a lot Charlie!!